# How to disable possibility to select particular child of InkCanvas?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using `InkCanvas` and I'm trying to disable selection for its particular child. `InkCanvas` children collection consists of `Eliipse` and `Path` objects and I want to disable possibility to select all of the `Path` objects. I was trying to achieve it by checking if mouse hit specific object in `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event handler:

```
private void myCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        Point downPosition = e.GetPosition(myCanvas);
        UIElement element = myPath;
        if (myCanvas.InputHitTest(downPosition) == element) e.Handled = true;
}
```

Now I know that it won't work because `InputHitTest` function returns `InkCanvas` selection adorner, if I click on the object one more time, when it is already selected above function works (at least `InputHitTest` is returning object that interests me). Do you have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: is it possible for you to share a sample of the app? it is little difficult to understand from the snippet.

Comment: It is hard for me to share a sample of the app, because whole app is quite complex. I believe that this snippet describes my problem quite well, if you would like to ask about details I would be happy to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far what I can see is that you want particular child of inkcanvas not be selected when clicking on canvas

so assuming you have a path called myPath

```
private void InkCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point downPosition = e.GetPosition(myPath);
    if (myPath.InputHitTest(downPosition) == myPath) 
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

so directly do hit test on the path and see if it return itself then you can determine a click on the path and then by setting e.Handled = true you make the event consumed hence the element will not be selected.

alternate approach will be testing with null, this will have the same behavior as above, so depends on choice

```
    if (myPath.InputHitTest(downPosition) != null) 
        e.Handled = true;
```

I propose the above solution based on assumption, you please correct me if this is not what you are looking for.